# Is there a way to print a webview using Flutter and a bluetooth thermal printer?

Tags: flutter, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I have an app that I need to print the content of a HTML page. The content is a sales receipt, structured to be printed by this kind of device. I'm using a webview *(flutter_inappwebview package)* to show this on app, but I need to print, so I did not get it yet.
**Is there a way to print this page?**